# How to maintain history when navigate from one ajax page to another simple page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to maintain history when I navigate from one page to another. On First page i use ajax to filter data. when I navigate to other page and click on back all filter reset.

Comment: filters are query parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to save the filter setting somewhere...session is probably best.